# Excel to .csv in Powershell keeps changing format of dates and long numbers

Tags: excel, powershell, csv, format, scientific-notation

Powershell script is as follows:

```
$E = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$E.Visible = $false
$E.DisplayAlerts = $false
$wb = $E.Workbooks.Open($args[0])
$wb_name = fix-wbname($wb.Name)
foreach ($ws in $wb.Worksheets)
{
    $n = $wb.Name + "_" + $ws.Name + ".csv"
    $n = Join-Path -Path $args[1] -ChildPath $n
    $ws.SaveAs($n, 6)
}
```

It works, but Excel does silly things to the text formatting. Dates in the YYYY-MM-DD format are changed to M/D/YYYY. The number 18446744073709500000 is changed to "1.84467E+19"

Is there any way I can do this and have Excel just export the values *as they are*?

Answer (score 0):

In general, no.  Dates in excel are not stored internally in the same format that you see them on the screen.  They are stored in some sort of binary numberger format that is almost undoubtedly the same format used internally in Windows.  I haven't researched this.  You are going to have to find out what default conversion takes place when the conversion to csv happens.  This could be culture dependent.

Culture dependencies can be controlled by settings inside of excel.  If the conversions to csv are being done by Powershell, you may be able to control culture dependecies by specifying optional parameters.

Sorry this is so vague.